# Garage Door opener with open and close contacts

Tags: garage-door, door-opener

Most garage door openers have a toggle input which closes, pauses, opens the doors.  I am looking for an **opener for a double garage door that has separate contacts for open and close**.  The remotes can work as they do normally.

The reason:

The last two houses had the toggle ones and automation becomes difficult.  To be able to say "Alexa close Garage Door", I have to have a routine that

- Presses the toggle
- Waits a prescribed time (measured earlier)
- If the (closed) sensor hasnt triggered, press the button again
- Repeat

If there were separate contacts, then this process becomes trivial.  I am looking at shifting to a new house and I want to make this simpler.